# How to Union from 2 table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
`tb_a` :         `tb_b`

========         ========
|id|key|         |id|key|
========         ========
| 1|  A|         | 1|  D|
| 2|  B|         | 2|  E|
| 3|  C|         | 3|  F|
| 4|  B|         | 4|  B|
========         | 5|  A|
                 | 6|  G|
                 ========
```

I want to union `key` from `tb_a` and `tb_b`. So the result must be = ABCDEFG.

The code that I have tried is:

```
SELECT id, key
  FROM tb_a
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, key
  FROM tb_b
ORDER BY id
```

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Also, if you only want the `key` column, is there a reason that you're selecting the `id` column as well?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `id` field in your query output since it will prevent from grouping output by `key`. Also don't use `UNION ALL`, use `UNION` instead:

```
SELECT  `key` 
FROM tb_a
UNION 
SELECT  `key` 
FROM tb_b
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use `CONCAT` in your sql query like this:

```
SELECT tb_a.id, tb_b.id, CONCAT(tb_a.key,tb_b.key) as Combined_key
FROM tb_a, tb_b
ORDER BY tb_a.id, tb_b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

If the problem you're having is duplicate values, it's because of UNION ALL. Use UNION alone instead.

Answer (score 0):

Joins do not map directly to the basic additive operations of set theory (union, intersect, difference), which create new sets by way of simply including or excluding elements of other sets. There are ways to get those in SQL, but it involves chaining UNION and MINUS statements.

Joins, rather, are mapping operations, which create new sets by taking an element from each set, according to a set of rules, and lumping them together in a new element for the new set that is actually itself a small set containing the original two elements from the other sets.

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name2
```

**Notice** that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order.

**Note**: The UNION operator selects only distinct values by default. To allow duplicate values, use UNION ALL.

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table_name2
```

**Good read**

[A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins - Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`key` ORDER BY `key` SEPARATOR '') AS 'key'
FROM (
    SELECT `key` FROM tb_a
    UNION
    SELECT `key` FROM tb_b
) a
GROUP BY NULL
```

**EDIT:** My bad. Here:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT `id`,`key` FROM tb_a
    UNION
    SELECT `id`,`key` FROM tb_b
) tb_ab
GROUP BY `key`
ORDER BY `key`
```

Although, your answer is not clear by which criterion should the `id` be determined.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `key` FROM (
  SELECT key FROM tb_a
  UNION
  SELECT key FROM tb_b
) AS t ORDER BY `key`
```